# Assistance understanding case when OutOfMemoryError thrown when parallel GC enabled

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I was following this link about the parallel garbage collector: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/parallel.html#parallel_collector_excessive_gc

It says:

"The parallel collector throws an OutOfMemoryError if too much time is being spent in garbage collection (GC): If more than 98% of the total time is spent in garbage collection and less than 2% of the heap is recovered, then an OutOfMemoryError is thrown."

I was looking for help understanding what "total time" means here? Is it the total time of a full GC? Is it total time of the JVM uptime? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us say you JVM is running during 100s if it dedicates 98s to the execution of GC and less than 2% of the heap is recovered, it will throw an OOM exception